# Determine where the largest integer function has a limit.

Tags: real-analysis

The question is as follows:
Let $\lfloor x \rfloor$ denote the largest integer that is less than or equal to $x$. Determine at which points $f(x)=\lfloor x \rfloor$ has a limit. Justify your conclusions.

I already know where the thing has limits. It's $R/Z$. Can I justify it just by saying that the left and right limits at each integer are unequal? It doesn't specifically say *prove* where the limits exist, but I kind of feel like I am supposed to.

...If I do enough of these things, eventually I'll get a clue about how to get started. Thank you for any direction.

Comment: For any noninteger $x$, $f$ is constant in a neighborhood of $x$, thus the limit exists at those points. If $x$ is an integer, then yes, we can see that the left and right limits are unequal, thus the limit does not exist when $x$ is an integer. Thus we have shown an "if and only if" statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If this is for a class, you might want to ask your professor how much detail and mathematical rigor he's looking for in your answers. That said, the problem that your given says "justify your conclusions" which seems to me to suggest that it's  looking for a general explanation as to why the limit exists at certain points and not others. It doesn't look to me as though it's necessarily looking for a proof. That said, it's quite easy to prove this, so why not go the full nine yards?

To show that $$\lim_{x \to a} f(x)$$ does not exist when $a \in \mathbb{Z}$, it is sufficient to show that for each such $a$ we have

$$\lim_{x \to a^-} f(x) \neq \lim_{x \to a^+}f(x)$$.

However, you will want to write a proof showing what each of these limits is and that they are not equal.

Once you're done with this, you still have one more step left that you need to take to prove your claim. You need to show that for every $a \in \mathbb{R} \setminus \mathbb{Z}$ we have $$\lim_{x \to a} f(x) = b$$ where $b \in \mathbb{R}$.

To show this, use an $\epsilon$-$\delta$ proof.

Let $\epsilon > 0$ and let $L = \lfloor a \rfloor$. We want to prove that

$$\lim_{x \to a} f(x) = L$$.

If $x < L$ or $x > L + 1$ then $\left| f(x) - L \right| =\left| \lfloor x \rfloor - \lfloor a \rfloor \right| \geq 1$.

If $L < x < L + 1$ then $\left| f(x) - L \right| = 0$. Therefore, let $\delta = \min (\left| L - a \right|, \epsilon)$. Then for every $x \in \mathbb{R}$, $\epsilon > 0$ we have

$$\left| x - a \right| < \delta \implies \left| f(x) - L \right| < \epsilon$$ This completes the proof.

Comment: Okay, so I decided to try proving the limit DNE at integers. Tell me if this works:
Let $x_0$ be an integer. Assume that $\lim_{x\to x_0}[x]=L$. Choose $\varepsilon = \frac{1}{4}$. There is $\delta > 0 $ such that $0 < |x-x_0|< \delta $ implies $|f(x)-L|<\frac{1}{4}$. Let $p=x_0 - \frac{1}{2}$ and let $q=x_0 + \frac{1}{2}$ . Then $f(p)=x_0 -1$ and $f(q)=x_0$. And so
$1=|f(p)-f(q)|\leq |f(p)-L|+|L-f(q)| < \frac{1}{4} + \frac{1}{4}= \frac{1}{2}$

This is a contradiction, so it follows that f does not have a limit when x is an integer. ((Only ?: i feel like i should've gotten $\delta$ in somehow)

Comment: I'm dumb. I should just say let $p=x_0-\frac{1}{\delta}$ and let $q=x_0+\frac{1}{\delta}$. Now $\delta $ is into it.

Comment: Wait, no, does this work? This wouldn't work if $\delta < 1$... crap.

Comment: Yeah, your proof does not work because there is no guarantee that $x_0 -  \frac{1}{2}$, $x_0 +  \frac{1}{2}$, $x_0 -  \frac{1}{\delta}$, or $x_0 +  \frac{1}{\delta}$ are less than $\delta$.

Comment: To prove the limit does not exist you need to negate the $\epsilon$-$\delta$ definition of a limit. So you need to show that there exists an $\epsilon$ such that for every $\delta > 0$, $\left| x - x_0 \right| < \delta \implies \left| f(x) - f(x_0) \right| \geq \epsilon$. Can you think of some such $\epsilon$ that might work for this purpose?

Comment: You were on the right track with your proof, it just needs some revision.